# I don't understand why I can't install this pip package?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text-to-speech, coqui

I'm trying to install TTS, but it's not allowing me to?
Please help!!

Python version is 3.8.10 //
Linux version Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS // Running on WSL2

[image]

Comment: Did you create your own module named `enum`? It'd override the standard library one.

Comment: [`enum.IntFlag` definitely exists in 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys... and apologies for the rookie error, but I just needed to update pip!